# How to find on which updates site the plugin is located?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I know, that somewhere on some update site an eclipse RCP plugin "org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.liveeditor" is located. how do i find the right update site? 
Is there a posibility to search the update sites for a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you have to go to the website for the plugin to find out where the download is.  I've seen so much variation in update site locations that I've given up on looking anywhere but the plugin's website.  Let Google be your index.

Answer (score 1):

Google is still the best there: The [vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#tutorial_installation2) points to the update site http://download.eclipse.org/e4/updates/0.12